# I want timer to expire after once it is used in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Im using Timer() in Flutter to switch between screens, I have screen1 which switches to screen2 after some delay and back to screen1 after some delay.

I want the functionalities to work the same way but I want the switching to be done just once. Right now, after I run the timer, the screens keep on switching back and forth (which is logically correct since I am not using any function to expire the Timer()). I want to know how to expire the Timer() so it does not switch more than once. Here is my code.

```
class _SpeedometerScreenState extends State<SpeedometerScreen> {

  var duration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() async {
    duration = Duration(seconds: 5);
    return Timer(duration, route);
  }

  route() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => MapScreen(),
       ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(...);
  }

}
```

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are switching back from page 2 (MapScreen) to page 1 (SpeedometerScreen)?

Comment: I have written the same codes in both files just the difference is the Navigator.pushReplacement() method. In MapScreen() im pushing into SpeedometerScreen() and vice versa.

Comment: Use `Navigator.pop(context);` in MapScreen, it will fix your issue.

Comment: sorry my bad, I want them to keep on switching as long as I am on either of the screens, but as soon as I turn to a 3rd screen, I want the timer to stop immediately. Right now it keeps on running in the background and no matter where I am it switches back to the Map or Speedometer screen depending on  whose turn it is...any guesses what could be done to avoid switching even after I switch to a 3rd screen?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you need any other details

Comment: I think you're asking how to expire a timer when it's no longer necessary.  Your question title asks how to expire it after it is used, but non-periodic `Timer`s already expire once they fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the created timer in your code and when you want to cancel that call [cancel()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/cancel.html) on that timer object.

```
class _SpeedometerScreenState extends State<SpeedometerScreen> {
  Timer _timer;

  Timer startTimer() {
    var duration = Duration(seconds: 5);
    return Timer(duration, route);
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = startTimer();
  }

  _cancelTimer() {
    if (_timer?.isActive) {
      _timer.cancel()
    }
  }

  // Your other code
}
```

Call _cancelTimer when you navigate to third-page. Since you have two different class which has two different timers, you've to write this in both classes.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Worked Just the way I wanted. :))

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is a solution or workaround but it'll fit to your purpose.

In screen1, add a constructor in the parameter. Let's say the parameter name is `isComingFromScreen2`. The default value would be false.

In screen 2, you call screen1 with `isComingFromScreen2 : true`.

Now, in screen1, initState(), you can decide whether to start the timer or not depending on the value of `isComingFromScreen2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 600),(timer){
  timer.cancel(); //cancel time after first invoke
  //your code
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.